# Why does SSL not work for my Spring Boot application?

Tags: spring-boot, ssl, spring-security

I'm trying to get SSL to work. I have generated my SSL file `.p12` and now I have writen in the configuration inside my `application.yml`.

Still the port `8080` is used. Why?

```
server:
  port: 8443
  ssl:
    key-store: classpath:myFile.p12
    key-store-password: myPassword
    key-store-type: PKCS12
    key-alias: mySSLAlias
    key-password: myPassword
```

And the terminal output:

```
Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
```

So I can only still connect `http://localhost:8080`, not `https://localhost:8443`

Why?

I'm using Spring Security as well.

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/Intranet/AdminCrudView", "/Intranet/Bokning").authenticated() 
        .antMatchers("/**", "/Intranet**").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/").permitAll()
        .and()
        .oauth2Login().defaultSuccessUrl("/Intranet");
    }
}
```

Here is my complete `application.yml` file:

```
spring:

  datasource:
    driverClassName: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/spektrakonhemsida?serverTimezone=CET&createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
    username: myUser
    password: myPassword

  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
    show-sql: false
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update

  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
           facebook:
              clientId: myID
              clientSecret: mySecret
              accessTokenUri: https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token
              userAuthorizationUri: https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth
              tokenName: oauth_token
              authenticationScheme: query
              clientAuthenticationScheme: form
              resource:
                 userInfoUri: https://graph.facebook.com/me


  mail:
    host: smtp.gmail.com
    port: 587
    username: myGmail@gmail.com
    password: myPassword
    properties:
       mail:
         smtp:
           auth: true
         starttls:
           enable: true

  crud:
    adminfacebookemail: myFacebookEmail@outlook.com

  vaadin:
    productionMode: true

  server:
    port: 8443
    ssl:
      key-store: classpath:mySSLFile.p12
      key-store-password: myPassword
      key-store-type: PKCS12
      key-alias: myAlias
      key-password: myPassword
```

Comment: Is your application.yaml in the right place? Are the values overwritten by any other configuratoin?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Yes. the `.yml` file is in `src/main/resources`. No the values are not over written. There is no much text inside my `.yml` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it!

It cannot be

```
  server:
    port: 8443
    ssl:
      key-store: classpath:mySSLFile.p12
      key-store-password: myPassword
      key-store-type: PKCS12
      key-alias: myAlias
      key-password: myPassword
```

It must be two less spaces, like this:

```
server:
  port: 8443
  ssl:
    key-store: classpath:mySSLFile.p12
    key-store-password: myPassword
    key-store-type: PKCS12
    key-alias: myAlias
    key-password: myPassword
```

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Me too, but they need to fix these kind of problems.

Comment: I avoid YAML when ever I can